# MongoDB set a sub item in an array

Tags: mongodb

in the collection

```
{ _id: 123,
    category: 1,
    desc: 'desc',
    price: 99,
    item: 
     [ { two: '24',
     three: '48' },
       { two: '',
      three:''},
       { two: '33',
      three:'24'},
        ] } ,
{ _id: 121,
    category: 1,
    desc: 'desc',
    price: 99,
    item: 
     [ { two: '24',
     three: '58' },
       { two: '',
      three:''},
       { two: '35',
      three:'54'},
        ] }
```

how do i set the value 'two' to null for all record where item.two = '24'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use positional operator [$](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/#op._S_) to update document from items array which matched search query:

```
update({ "item.two" : "24" }, 
       { $set : { "item.$.two" : "" }}, false, true);
```

If you want to remove this field from array documents, then use [$unset](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/unset/) operator:

```
update({ "item.two" : "25" }, 
       { $unset : { "item.$.two" : "" }}, false, true);
```

Comment: update({ "item.two" : { $in : ['24','30']} }, 
       { $unset : { "item.$.two" : "" }}, false, true); is not working. can you help me out here. :) and if there are multiple item with two=24 in one collection how can i update it

Comment: @NisanthSojan I don't think that update of multiple array items is possible in single query. You can look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14720734/mongodb-update-multiple-records-of-array) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669178/how-to-update-multiple-array-elements-in-mongodb) for workarounds.